# Google Action, account linking: Insert a code after authentication

Tags: node.js, oauth, dialogflow-es

I've implemented Account linking via Auth0 for my Google Action. It works, but I need the user to insert a specific code just after the authentication, and have this code sent back to the action as variable. How can I manage this task?

I'm developing the action in Dialogflow. The authentication works.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "add a code"? What is this code for? Why do you need to do this?

Comment: By "code" I mean an identification alphanumeric string, like "CODE1234". I simply need to have this code "linked" to the user. The action will call Webhooks for some commands, something like: https://io.adafruit.com/api/v2/webhooks/feed/[CODE]/. So each user will call the proper Webhook. I hope it's clear enough. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. There is no part of the OAuth protocol that allows additional payload that has meaningful information.

However, you should be able to do this through Auth0 itself. You can add [custom claims](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/adoption/scope-custom-claims) that are stored as part of the userinfo. Then, when you get the auth token from your action, use this auth token to [get the user profile](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#user-profile) (including the code) from Auth0.

Comment: I'm afraid this is a little bit out of my "skill". I've tried to follow the two links you suggested but it's not that clear to me how to implement. Is there any tutorial around?